# Super user answer copied on another site

Tags: discussion

[Unable to format disk: 'The system cannot find the file specified'](https://superuser.com/questions/509992/unable-to-format-disk-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

answer used here:

https://itectec.com/superuser/unable-to-format-disk-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified/

Is this allowed or legal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is this allowed or legal?

Yes, it is allowed.

It is only legal if it includes attribution, which this example doesn't.

> In principle, there's actually nothing wrong with doing this. Our content is licensed under Creative Commons BY-SA 4.0 and is freely redistribituble, so long as they follow the attribution requirements and link back to us as the source. Some sites, however, do not follow these rules or bring up other concerns in the process.
>
> **How do I go about reporting these sites?**
>
> Please [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) directly using the on-site form. Select the "Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution" option from the drop-down, and provide as much information as possible. Even if you are reporting an entire site that is scraping many questions, please provide an example of a question on their site and the corresponding question on our site, as well as any Google search terms you used that led you to finding this site. Any other information you might have can be included in the free-form text box.

Source [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/267099), answer by [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525).

I have reported the site as per the above instructions.